# iOS - Identifying the App from which an API call is made

Tags: ios, api, security

We are trying to make a secure API call from the device to the server with sensitive data. We want to make sure that the call is originating from the correct App. Is there a way the Apple app signing certificate can be verified by a 3rd party Server.

Comment: No.  You will need to include some other shared secret or challenge-response mechanism in your app